# PowerShell scripts to automate BizTalk configurations

Tags: .net, powershell, automation, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I need help to automate BizTalk configurations like Send/Receive locations etc.
I think we can achieve this using PowerShell scripts.

Any suggestions?

Note: We are have on-premise infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

For facilitating the Admin-time configuration of BizTalk Server, Ports, Bindings, etc. you would focus on using Binding Files.

While Powershell can be part of this, Powershell itself is not what would drive the configuration.

Perhaps what you should really be looking at is automating app deployment using the [Deployment Framework for BizTalk (BTDF)](https://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Johns-305's answer - if you're trying to configure the application bindings, you should leverage bindings files and definitely look at using BTDF to manage multiple environments.

If, on the other hand, you're trying to automate setting up hosts/host instances/adapter handlers, PowerShell can be a great tool to streamline rolling that out consistently across environments.  You can do it using the BizTalk PowerShell provider (multiple examples of how to use that [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32456.powershell-script-for-creating-biztalk-hostshost-instancesadapter-handlers-and-custom-event-log.aspx#Creating_Adapter_Handlers), or using WMI (great example of that [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-to-Configure-0cee83e8).

From that second link, here's an example of deleting or creating an adapter handler using WMI (which doesn't require any special add-ins like the BizTalk PowerShell provider - although it's a great add-in to have, it's not always available for a given environment):

```
#############################################################
# This function will delete an existente host handlers 
# in the adapters.
# [direction]: 'Receive','Send'
#############################################################
function DeleteBizTalkAdapterHandler (
    [string]$adapterName,
    [string]$direction,
    [string]$hostName)
{
    try
    {
        if($direction -eq 'Receive')
        {
            [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHandler = get-wmiobject 'MSBTS_ReceiveHandler' -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter "HostName='$hostName' AND AdapterName='$adapterName'"
            $objHandler.Delete()
        }
        else
        {
            [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHandler = get-wmiobject 'MSBTS_SendHandler2' -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter "HostName='$hostName' AND AdapterName='$adapterName'"
            $objHandler.Delete()
        }

        Write-Host "$direction handler for $adapterName / $hostName was successfully deleted" -Fore DarkGreen
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.")
        {
            Write-Host "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName does not exist" -Fore DarkRed
        }
        elseif ($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf("Cannot delete a receive handler that is used by") -ne -1)
        {
            Write-Host "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName is in use and can't be deleted." -Fore DarkRed
        }
        elseif ($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf("Cannot delete a send handler that is used by") -ne -1)
        {
            Write-Host "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName is in use and can't be deleted." -Fore DarkRed
        }
        elseif ($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf("Cannot delete this object since at least one receive location is associated with it") -ne -1)
        {
            Write-Host "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName is in use by at least one receive location and can't be deleted." -Fore DarkRed
        }
        else
        {
            write-Error "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName could not be deleted: $_.Exception.ToString()"
        }
    }
}

#############################################################
# This function will create a handler for a specific 
# adapter on the new host, so these get used for processing.
# [direction]: 'Receive','Send'
#############################################################
function CreateBizTalkAdapterHandler(
    [string]$adapterName,
    [string]$direction,
    [string]$hostName,
    [string]$originalDefaulHostName,
    [boolean]$isDefaultHandler,
    [boolean]$removeOriginalHostInstance)
{
    if($direction -eq 'Receive')
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objAdapterHandler = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_ReceiveHandler").CreateInstance()
        $objAdapterHandler["AdapterName"] = $adapterName
        $objAdapterHandler["HostName"] = $hostName
    }
    else
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objAdapterHandler = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_SendHandler2").CreateInstance()
        $objAdapterHandler["AdapterName"] = $adapterName
        $objAdapterHandler["HostName"] = $hostName
        $objAdapterHandler["IsDefault"] = $isDefaultHandler
    }

    try
    {
        $putOptions = new-Object System.Management.PutOptions
        $putOptions.Type = [System.Management.PutType]::CreateOnly;

        [Type[]] $targetTypes = New-Object System.Type[] 1
        $targetTypes[0] = $putOptions.GetType()

        $sysMgmtAssemblyName = "System.Management"
        $sysMgmtAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sysMgmtAssemblyName)
        $objAdapterHandlerType = $sysMgmtAssembly.GetType("System.Management.ManagementObject")

        [Reflection.MethodInfo] $methodInfo = $objAdapterHandlerType.GetMethod("Put", $targetTypes)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($objAdapterHandler, $putOptions)

        Write-Host "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName was successfully created" -Fore DarkGreen
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("The specified BizTalk Host is already a receive handler for this adapter.") -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "$hostName is already a $direction Handler for $adapterName adapter." -Fore DarkRed
        }
        elseif($_.Exception.Message.Contains("The specified BizTalk Host is already a send handler for this adapter.") -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "$hostName is already a $direction Handler for $adapterName adapter." -Fore DarkRed
        }
        else {
            write-Error "$adapterName $direction Handler for $hostName could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()"
        }
    }

    if($removeOriginalHostInstance)
    {
        DeleteBizTalkAdapterHandler $adapterName $direction $originalDefaulHostName
    }
}
```